# Как разбить результат аудита по категориям?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagespeed-insights

Есть такая задача взять данные по ссылке(https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed/?url=https://www.duolingo.com/) это JSON и отобразить в компоненте Vue (c отображение проблем нет :) ). Данные берутся с `JSON -> lighthouseResult -> audits`.

Но перед тем как отображать данные нужно их предварительно разбить на категории **Passed Audits**, **Diagnostics**, **Opportunities** . 
Нашел примерный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636725/pagespeed-insights-api-v5 но из него мене не совсем ясно, как все таки разбить на категории? 
Результат аудита находится в объекте **audits** , а вот категории находятся в объекте **auditRefs**
Хотелось бы что бы подсказали как данные из объекта **audits** разбить по тем категориям, которые находятся в объекте **auditRefs**. 
Второй день не могу никак придумать... :(

Вот мой код https://codesandbox.io/s/google-api-test-p2oqq

Comment: А что не так в [версии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/983222/2) редакции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализаций данного вопроса может быть несколько. Основная логика в коде ниже:

- получение всех ссылок в зависимости от выбранной категории - [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter);
- формирование массива идентификаторов проверок - [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map);
- формирование массива проверок по массиву идентификаторов - map.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // Модель проверок: объект.
    audits: {},
    // Модель ссылок на проверки: массив.
    auditRefs: [],
    // Категории ссылок `auditRefs`.
    category: 'all',
    // Модель url страницы: строка.
    domain: '',
    // Модель ошибок, включая ошибки
    // при получении запроса.
    error: null,
    // Состояние готовности.
    ready: false,
  },

  computed: {
    // Вычисляемое свойство: ссылки на проверки `auditRefs`.
    // Зависит от выбранной категории.
    filteredAuditRefs() {
      return 'all' === this.category ?
        this.auditRefs :
        !this.category ?
        this.auditRefs.filter(item => !item.group) :
        this.auditRefs.filter(item => item.group === this.category)
    },
    
    // Вычисляемое свойство: проверки `audits`.
    // Зависит от вычисленных ссылок.
    filteredAudits() {
      let ids = this.filteredAuditRefs.map(item => item.id)
      let filtered = ids.map(id => this.audits[id])

      return filtered
    },
    
    // Вычисляемое свойство для класса.
    // Зависит от количества `score`:
    // набранных очков пункта по мнению спидины.
    scoreClass() {
      return (score) => {
        score = parseFloat(score) * 100

        return {
          'alert-success': score > 90,
          'alert-warning': score >= 50 && score <= 90,
          'alert-danger': score < 50,
        }
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    // Выполнение запроса к спидине.
    async fetchResource() {
      try {
        this.ready = 'loading'
        this.error = ''

        if (!this.domain) {
          throw new Error('Введите действительный URL.')
        }

        const domain = this.domain.toString().replace(/^https?:\//, '')
        const response = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed/?url=http://${domain}&locale=ru_RU`)
        const json = await response.json()

        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
          this.audits = json.lighthouseResult.audits
          this.auditRefs = json.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.auditRefs
        } else {
          throw new Error(json.error.errors[0].message)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error
      } finally {
        this.ready = true
      }
    }
  },
  
  filters: {
    // Фильтр для разметки ссылки `markdown`
    mdLnks(value) {
      if (!value) return ''
      value = value.toString()

      return value.replace(/[\[]{1}([^\]]+)[\]]{1}[\(]{1}([^\)\"]+)(\"(.+)\")?[\)]{1}/g, '<a href="$2" title="$4" target="_blank">$1</a>')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.form {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.alert {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
}

.alert-info {
  color: #2f6473;
  background-color: #def2f8;
  border-color: #d1edf6;
}

.alert-success {
  color: #235937;
  background-color: #d9eee1;
  border-color: #cae8d5;
}

.alert-warning {
  color: #794b01;
  background-color: #fbe9cc;
  border-color: #f9e0b8;
}

.alert-danger {
  color: #7d2213;
  background-color: #fcd9d3;
  border-color: #fbcac2;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form" @submit.prevent="fetchResource">
      <input type="url" v-model="domain" placeholder="Введите URL веб-страницы" />
      <button type="submit" :hidden="ready"> АНАЛИЗИРОВАТЬ </button>

      <select v-if="filteredAudits.length" v-model="category">
        <option value="all">- All -</option>
        <option value="">passed</option>
        <option value="metrics">Имитация загрузки страницы</option>
        <option value="load-opportunities">Оптимизация</option>
        <option value="diagnostics">Диагностика</option>
        <option value="budgets">budgets</option>
      </select>
    </form>

    <div v-if="ready && filteredAudits.length">

      <!-- Тут лучше использовать дочерние компоненты. -->
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(audit, index) in filteredAudits">
          <h4>{{ audit.title }}</h4>
          <p :class="['alert', scoreClass(audit.score)]">
            <b>{{ audit.score }}</b>
            <!-- Фильтр для разметки ссылки `markdown` -->
            <span v-html="$options.filters.mdLnks(audit.description)"></span>
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div v-if="ready && error" class="alert alert-danger">{{ error }}</div>
    <div v-if="'loading' === ready" class="alert alert-info">Загрузка данных, ожидайте ...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10'></script>
```

**PS** Получение информации с сервиса google занимает примерно 10-15 сек.

Comment: Низкий вам поклон :)  спасибо!